# Knn algorithm in regression

Tags: python, pandas, knn

| Number of plants | Total kg |
| --- | --- |
| 900 | 7.565 |
| 1440 | 17.808 |
| 2340 | 25.373 |
| 900 | 10.340 |
| 900 | 10.610 |

I have a data set and I am trying to predict the "Total kg" based on the "Number of plants" using KNN.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

df = pd.read_csv(r'final2.csv')

X = df.drop('Total kg', axis=1)
Y = df[["Total kg"]]

X=X.values
Y=Y.values

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
  
prediction = knn.fit(X,Y)
```

I get the following error: ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'

Is there a way to use KNN for continuous variables?

Comment: What makes you think that KNN are appropriate here? Wouldn't a more classical curve fitting work for you?

Comment: I have done already research on this, I tried linear regression but the assumptions are not fulfilled, regression tree was another option but when comparing the MAE the results were significantly worst than KNN. I did all those tests using Weka Experimenter.

Comment: I have another question maybe not really related if you know when checking the assumptions for Linear Regression, should I check for the entire data set or for the 80% split which I use to train the model?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a classifier for a regression task. Try:

```
knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    import plotly.express as px

# Scaling
    from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# Train Test Split
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Models
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier

# Metrics
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report, roc_curve

# Cross Validation
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

    import warnings
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

    df = pd.read_csv("heart.csv")

# Preview of the first 10 rows of the data
    df.head(10)

    df.dtypes

#shape of data
    print("The shape of the dataset is : ", df.shape)

**Get Categorical Column**
    string_col=df.select_dtypes("string").columns.to_list()

**#Check the number of unique values in each column**
    dict = {}
    for i in list(df.columns):
    dict[i] = df[i].value_counts().shape[0]

    pd.DataFrame(dict,index=["unique count"]).transpose()

**check duplicated**
    df[df.duplicated()]

**Remove duplicate**
    df.drop_duplicates(keep='first',inplace=True)

**check new shape**
    print('Number of rows are',df.shape[0], 'and number of columns are ',df.shape[1])

    num_col=df.columns.to_list()
    for col in string_col:
    num_col.remove(col)
    num_col.remove("output")

    df[string_col].head()
    for col in string_col:
    print(f"The distribution of categorical valeus in the {col} is : ")
    print(df[col].value_counts())

**check statistical data**
    df.describe()
    df.coor()


**seperate the column in categorical and continious**
    cat_cols = ['sex','exng','caa','cp','fbs','restecg','slp','thall']
    con_cols = ["age","trtbps","chol","thalachh","oldpeak"]
    target_col = ["output"]
    print("The categorial cols are : ", cat_cols)
    print("The continuous cols are : ", con_cols)
    print("The target variable is :  ", target_col)

    df[con_cols].describe().transpose()

# EDA#
    pair plot
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
    sns.pairplot(df,hue='output',palette = ["#8000ff","#da8829"])
    plt.show()

    violin plot
    plt.figure(figsize=(18, 10))
    plt.subplot(2,3,1)
    sns.violinplot(x = 'sex', y = 'output', data = df)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)

    plt.subplot(2,3,2)
    sns.violinplot(x = 'thall', y = 'output', data = df)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)

    plt.subplot(2,3,3)
    sns.violinplot(x = 'exng', y = 'output', data = df)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)

    plt.subplot(2,3,4)
    sns.violinplot(x = 'restecg', y = 'output', data = df)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)

    plt.subplot(2,3,5)
    sns.violinplot(x = 'cp', y = 'output', data = df)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)

    plt.subplot(2,3,6)
    sns.violinplot(x = 'fbs', y = 'output', data = df)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

    heatmap
    px.imshow(df.corr(),title="Correlation Plot of the Heat Failure Prediction")

    plt.figure(figsize= (16, 8))
    sns.heatmap(df.corr(), annot = True, cmap= 'gnuplot2_r', fmt= '.1f');

# Count plot of categorical features#
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,15))
    gs = fig.add_gridspec(3,3)
    gs.update(wspace=0.5, hspace=0.25)
    ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,2])
    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,0])
    ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,1])
    ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,2])
    ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2,0])
    ax7 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2,1])
    ax8 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2,2])

    background_color = "#ffe6e6"
    color_palette = ["#800000","#8000ff","#6aac90","#5833ff","#da8829"]
    fig.patch.set_facecolor(background_color)
    ax0.set_facecolor(background_color)
    ax1.set_facecolor(background_color)
    ax2.set_facecolor(background_color)
    ax3.set_facecolor(background_color)
    ax4.set_facecolor(background_color)
    ax5.set_facecolor(background_color)
    ax6.set_facecolor(background_color)
    ax7.set_facecolor(background_color)
    ax8.set_facecolor(background_color)

# Title of the plot
    ax0.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
    ax0.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
    ax0.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
    ax0.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
    ax0.tick_params(left=False, bottom=False)
    ax0.set_xticklabels([])
    ax0.set_yticklabels([])
    ax0.text(0.5,0.5,
         'Count plot for various\n categorical features\n_________________',
         horizontalalignment='center',
         verticalalignment='center',
         fontsize=18, fontweight='bold',
         fontfamily='serif',
         color="#000000")

# Sex count
    ax1.text(0.3, 220, 'Sex', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', fontfamily='serif',     color="#000000")
    ax1.grid(color='#000000', linestyle=':', axis='y', zorder=0,  dashes=(1,5))
    sns.countplot(ax=ax1,data=df,x='sex',palette=color_palette)
    ax1.set_xlabel("")
    ax1.set_ylabel("")

# Exng count
    ax2.text(0.3, 220, 'Exng', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', fontfamily='serif', color="#000000")
    ax2.grid(color='#000000', linestyle=':', axis='y', zorder=0,  dashes=(1,5))
    sns.countplot(ax=ax2,data=df,x='exng',palette=color_palette)
    ax2.set_xlabel("")
    ax2.set_ylabel("")

# Caa count
    ax3.text(1.5, 200, 'Caa', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', fontfamily='serif', color="#000000")
    ax3.grid(color='#000000', linestyle=':', axis='y', zorder=0,  dashes=(1,5))
    sns.countplot(ax=ax3,data=df,x='caa',palette=color_palette)
    ax3.set_xlabel("")
    ax3.set_ylabel("")

# Cp count
    ax4.text(1.5, 162, 'Cp', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', fontfamily='serif', color="#000000")
    ax4.grid(color='#000000', linestyle=':', axis='y', zorder=0,  dashes=(1,5))
    sns.countplot(ax=ax4,data=df,x='cp',palette=color_palette)
    ax4.set_xlabel("")
    ax4.set_ylabel("")

# Fbs count
    ax5.text(0.5, 290, 'Fbs', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', fontfamily='serif', color="#000000")
    ax5.grid(color='#000000', linestyle=':', axis='y', zorder=0,  dashes=(1,5))
    sns.countplot(ax=ax5,data=df,x='fbs',palette=color_palette)
    ax5.set_xlabel("")
    ax5.set_ylabel("")

# Restecg count
    ax6.text(0.75, 165, 'Restecg', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', fontfamily='serif', color="#000000")
    ax6.grid(color='#000000', linestyle=':', axis='y', zorder=0,  dashes=(1,5))
    sns.countplot(ax=ax6,data=df,x='restecg',palette=color_palette)
    ax6.set_xlabel("")
    ax6.set_ylabel("")

# Slp count
    ax7.text(0.85, 155, 'Slp', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', fontfamily='serif', color="#000000")
    ax7.grid(color='#000000', linestyle=':', axis='y', zorder=0,  dashes=(1,5))
    sns.countplot(ax=ax7,data=df,x='slp',palette=color_palette)
    ax7.set_xlabel("")
    ax7.set_ylabel("")

# Thall count
    ax8.text(1.2, 180, 'Thall', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', fontfamily='serif', color="#000000")
    ax8.grid(color='#000000', linestyle=':', axis='y', zorder=0,  dashes=(1,5))
    sns.countplot(ax=ax8,data=df,x='thall',palette=color_palette)
    ax8.set_xlabel("")
    ax8.set_ylabel("")

    for s in ["top","right","left"]:
    ax1.spines[s].set_visible(False)
    ax2.spines[s].set_visible(False)
    ax3.spines[s].set_visible(False)
    ax4.spines[s].set_visible(False)
    ax5.spines[s].set_visible(False)
    ax6.spines[s].set_visible(False)
    ax7.spines[s].set_visible(False)
    ax8.spines[s].set_visible(False)

# boxen plot of continious features
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,16))
    gs = fig.add_gridspec(2,3)
    gs.update(wspace=0.3, hspace=0.15)
    ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,2])
    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,0])
    ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,1])
    ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,2])

    background_color = "#ffe6e6"
    color_palette = ["#800000","#8000ff","#6aac90","#5833ff","#da8829"]
    fig.patch.set_facecolor(background_color)
    ax0.set_facecolor(background_color)
    ax1.set_facecolor(background_color)
    ax2.set_facecolor(background_color)
    ax3.set_facecolor(background_color)
    ax4.set_facecolor(background_color)
    ax5.set_facecolor(background_color)

# Title of the plot
    ax0.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
    ax0.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
    ax0.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
    ax0.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
    ax0.tick_params(left=False, bottom=False)
    ax0.set_xticklabels([])
    ax0.set_yticklabels([])
    ax0.text(0.5,0.5,
         'Boxen plot for various\n continuous features\n_________________',
         horizontalalignment='center',
         verticalalignment='center',
         fontsize=18, fontweight='bold',
         fontfamily='serif',
         color="#000000")

# Age
    ax1.text(-0.05, 81, 'Age', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', fontfamily='serif', color="#000000")
    ax1.grid(color='#000000', linestyle=':', axis='y', zorder=0,  dashes=(1,5))
    sns.boxenplot(ax=ax1,y=df['age'],palette=["#800000"],width=0.6)
    ax1.set_xlabel("")
    ax1.set_ylabel("")

# Trtbps
    ax2.text(-0.05, 208, 'Trtbps', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', fontfamily='serif', color="#000000")
    ax2.grid(color='#000000', linestyle=':', axis='y', zorder=0,  dashes=(1,5))
    sns.boxenplot(ax=ax2,y=df['trtbps'],palette=["#8000ff"],width=0.6)
    ax2.set_xlabel("")
    ax2.set_ylabel("")

# Chol
    ax3.text(-0.05, 600, 'Chol', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', fontfamily='serif', color="#000000")
    ax3.grid(color='#000000', linestyle=':', axis='y', zorder=0,  dashes=(1,5))
    sns.boxenplot(ax=ax3,y=df['chol'],palette=["#6aac90"],width=0.6)
    ax3.set_xlabel("")
    ax3.set_ylabel("")

# Thalachh
    ax4.text(-0.0
```

Comment: When writing an answer to a question, the idea is to work with the poster's example/problem scope and not generate an entirely different solution/code outside the provided problematic code.

Answer (score 1):

```
df_raw.info()
df_raw.describe()

df_corr = df_raw.corr()[['Age']].sort_values(by = 'Age')
sns.heatmap(df_corr, annot = True)

plt.title('Histogram for xx')
plt.hist(x = df_raw['Age'])
df_raw['Age'].hist()
plt.show()

sns.boxplot(x = df_raw['SibSp'], y = df_raw['Pclass'])

counts = df_raw['SibSp'].value_counts()[0]
counts

df_clean = df_raw[df_raw['SibSp'] != 0]
df_clean

df_clean.reset_index(drop=True)

avg = df_clean['SibSp'].median()
df_raw['SibSp'].replace(0, avg, inplace = True)
df_raw['SibSp'].value_counts()

df_raw['SibSp'].fillna(avg, inplace = True)
df_raw['SibSp'].dropna()
```

linear reggression

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lm = LinearRegression()

df_clean = df_raw[['age', 'height_cm', 'weight_kg']].dropna()
df_predictor = df_clean[['height_cm', 'weight_kg']].copy()
df_target = df_clean['age'].copy()

lm.fit(df_predictor, df_target)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lm = LinearRegression()

df_clean = df_raw[['age', 'height_cm', 'weight_kg']].dropna()
df_predictor = df_clean[['height_cm', 'weight_kg']].copy()
df_target = df_clean['age'].copy()

lm.fit(df_predictor, df_target)

df_cln1 = df_raw.copy()
df_impute = pd.DataFrame(lm.predict(df_raw[['height_cm', 'weight_kg']]))
df_impute.rename({0: 'age'}, axis = 1, inplace = True)
df_cln1.fillna(df_impute, inplace = True)
print(df_cln1.isna().sum())
```

feature engineering

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

categorical_variables = ['sex', 'fracture', 'medication']
data_cat = df_raw[categorical_variables]

cat_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
data_cat_onehot = cat_encoder.fit_transform(data_cat)
data_cat_onehot_df = pd.DataFrame(data_cat_onehot.toarray())

df_temp = pd.concat([df_raw, data_cat_onehot_df], axis = 1)
df_temp = df_temp.drop(categorical_variables, axis = 1)
df_eng = df_temp.copy()
df_eng

df_raw = df_raw.dropna()
```

split data

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(df_raw.drop('Target', axis = 1),
                                                      df_raw['Target'],
                                                      test_size = 0.3,
                                                      random_state = 99)
```

Model

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as mse
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

poly_feat = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2)

poly_mod_x = poly_feat.fit_transform(np.array(x_train))
poly_model = LinearRegression()
poly_model.fit(poly_mod_x, y_train)

poly_mod_x_val =  poly_feat.fit_transform(np.array(x_valid))
y_pred = poly_model.predict(np.array(poly_mod_x_val))
rmse = np.sqrt(mse(y_valid, y_pred))
r2_score = r2_score(y_pred, y_valid)

print("Polynomial Regression Model Performance Metrics")
print('RMSE: ', rmse)
print('R2  : ', r2_score)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

log_reg = LogisticRegression()
log_reg.fit(x_train, y_train)
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred_log = log_reg.predict(x_valid)
y_pred_lin = lin_reg.predict(x_valid)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

report = classification_report(y_valid, y_pred_log)
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_valid, y_pred_lin))
r2 = r2_score(y_valid, y_pred_lin)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC

naive_bayes = GaussianNB()
random_forest = RandomForestClassifier()
decision_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
svm = SVC()

grid.best_params_

from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier

estimator = [('Logistic Regression', LogisticRegression(random_state = 99)),
             ('Decision Tree', DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 99)),
             ('Random Forest', RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 99)),
             ('SVM', SVC(C = 1000, gamma = 0.0001, kernel = 'rbf', probability = True, random_state = 99))]

voting_model = VotingClassifier(estimators = estimator,
                                voting = 'soft')
voting_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
pred = voting_model.predict(x_valid)
report = classification_report(y_valid, pred)
print(report)

from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier

bagging_model = BaggingClassifier(n_estimators = 100,
                                  estimator = LogisticRegression())
bagging_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
pred = bagging_model.predict(x_valid)
report = classification_report(y_valid, pred)

from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier

adaboost_model = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators = 100,
                                    estimator = 
RandomForestClassifier())
adaboost_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
pred = adaboost_model.pred(x_valid)
report = classification_report(y_valid, pred)
```

Clustering KMeans

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k_range = range(1, 10)
inertias = []
k_model = []

for k in k_range:
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=10)
    kmeans.fit(df)
    inertias.append(kmeans.inertia_)
    k_model.append(kmeans)

plt.plot(list(k_range), inertias, "s-", linewidth=1)
plt.title('Elbow Chart')
plt.xlabel('Number of Clusters (k)')
plt.ylabel('Inertia')
plt.xticks(list(k_range))
plt.xlim(0, 9)
plt.ylim(0, 25000)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
silhoutte_scores = [silhouette_score(df1, model.labels_) for model in k_model[1:]]

plt.plot(range(2, 10), silhoutte_scores, "o-")
plt.title("Silhoutte Scores for k=1 to k=8")
plt.axis([1.5, 8.5, 0.4, 0.8])
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlim(0, 12)
plt.ylim(0,1)

from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 4)
kmeans.fit(df_raw)
y_kmeans = kmeans.predict(df_raw)

gaussian = GaussianMixture(n_components = 4)
gaussian.fit(df_raw)
y_gaussian = gaussian.predict(df_raw)

dbscan = DBSCAN(eps = 1.3, min_samples = 4)
dbscan.fit(df_raw)
y_dbscan = DBSCAN.predict(df_raw)

#standardize
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
x_standardize = scaler.fit_transform(df_raw.drop('Outcome', axis = 1))

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA()
pca.fit(x_standardize)
x_pca = pca.transform(x_standardize)

variance = pca.explained_variance_ratio
sns.barplot(x = list(range(1, len(variance)+1)), y = variance)
variance

#pca
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
x_standardize = scaler.fit_transform(x)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA()
pca.fit(x_standardize)
x_pca = pca.transform(x_standardize)

cat = ['sex', 'age', 'BMI']
df = df_raw.dropna().copy()
df_pred = df_raw[cat]
df_resp = df_raw[['healthy']]

lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(df_pred, df_resp)
df_new = df['healthy'].fillna(lin_reg.predict(df_raw[cat]))

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 5)
kmeans.fit(df_raw)
y_kmeans = kmeans.predict(df_raw)

gaus_mix = GaussianMixture(n_components = 5)
gaus_mix.fit(df_raw)
y_gaus = gaus_mix.predict(df_raw)

dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=1.2)
dbscan.fit(df_raw)
y_dbscan = dbscan.predict(df_raw)

naive_bayes = GaussianNB()
naive_bayes.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = naive_bayes.predict(x_valid)
report = classification_report(y_valid, y_pred)

df_corr = df_raw.corr()[['Outcome']].sort_values(by = 'Outcome')
sns.heatmap(df_corr, annot = True)

sns.scatterplot(x = , y = , hue = )

inertia = []
K = range(1, 10)

for i in K:
  kmeans = KMeans(n_clsuters = i)
  kmeans.fit(df_raw)
  inertia.append(kmeans.inertia_)

plt.plot(K, inertia)
plt.xlabel('K')
plt.ylabel('Inertia')
plt.show()

numeric_columns = list(df_raw.select_dtypes(include = [np.number]).columns)
for i, col in enumerate(numeric_columns):
  plt.figure()
  sns.boxplot(data = df_raw, x = 'Target', y = col)

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
cat = ['Sex', 'Embarked']
df_cat = df_raw[cat]
df_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df_cat)

df_new = pd.concat([df_raw, df_encoded])
df_new = df_new.drop(cat, axis = 1)

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

params_grid = {'C': [1, 10 , 100, 1000],
               'gamma' : [0.00001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1],
               'kernel': ['rbf']}

grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(), params_grid, refit = True, verbose = 1)

grid.best_params_

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

#still broken
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2)

lm.fit(poly_reg, y)

x_val_poly = poly_reg(x_val)
```

Comment: from google.colab import files

upload = files.upload()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).